# Can I execute two different queries in a single method using jdbc code?

Tags: jdbc

Can I execute two different queries in a single method using `jdbc` code?

Answer (score 0):

try **executeBatch()** method of Statement Interface of JDBC.

```
import java.sql.*;  
class Demo{  
   public static void main(String args[])throws Exception 
  {

     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
     Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","password");  
     con.setAutoCommit(false);  

     Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
     stmt.addBatch("insert into emp values(001,'abc',40000)");  
     stmt.addBatch("insert into emp values(002,'mni',50000)");  

     stmt.executeBatch();//executing the batch  

     con.commit();  
     con.close();  


}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

YES, 2 updates as a single statement

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc.url","jdbc.username","jdbc.password");

java.sql.Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

String sqlStr = "update tab set col1= 'X' \n update tab_not_exist set col1='X2'"; 

statemet.execute(sqlStr);
```

Can you please elaborate , what do you wish to achieve.